# Query/test if K8S API request is authorized before executing

Tags: rest, kubernetes

## Background

Consider a set of HTTP `GET` and `PUT` requests that I would like to issue to the K8S REST API. I know that the currently running pod (i.e. assume a single pod in the cluster for one-off testing/debugging/etc.) has the appropriate credentials (i.e. associated with the service account) to execute these calls successfully.

I would like to modify my requests so that they use a different service account to execute the request (i.e. modify the `user` field of the request). However, there's no guarantee the user is permitted to make **all** of these requests, and some could be destructive, so it's ideal that one of the two scenarios occur:

- None of the requests are executed.
- 100% of the requests are executed.

By having just some of the requests succeed, it can put a system into an indeterminate state.

---

## Question

Is there an API/feature in K8S where I can pre-determine if a specific API request, on the behalf of a specific user/service-account, will be permitted to execute?

Comment: Are you talking about Kubernetes RBAC https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac ?

Comment: @VasilyAngapov Along those lines, yes. I have a few service accounts, along with the associated clusterrole and clusterrolebindings, and want to effectively iterate over all the service accounts to see if they're capable of issuing certain API calls (using certain verbs, HTTP methods, etc.) against various endpoints. This is to generate a "resultant set of policy" (i.e. RSOP) report.

Comment: Have you tried for example "kubectl --as YOUR_SA auth can-i create pod". It gives nice understanding of what particular user or serviceaccount is capable of.

Comment: @VasilyAngapov Yes, I have tested certain capabilities via `kubectl auth can-i`. Now, I would like to do so more "programatically" by generating reports via REST API calls and parsing structured data (i.e. JSON/YAML) rather than having to manually parse/grep `kubectl` CLI/console output.

Comment: @VasilyAngapov I guess the question could be restructured as "How can I run `kubectl auth can-i` for arbitrary verbs/HTTP-methods via the REST API (without manually running `kubectl`)".

Comment: You can try "-v 10" flag for kubectl, it will show you corresponding REST request.

Comment: @VasilyAngapov That gets me closer. The only remaining piece I really need is to find the formal documentation on how the REST call is formulated, rather than reverse-engineering it from logging dumps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ kubectl -v 10 --as system:serviceaccount:default:jenkins auth can-i create pod
...
I0426 20:27:33.008777    4149 request.go:942] Request Body: {"kind":"SelfSubjectAccessReview","apiVersion":"authorization.k8s.io/v1","metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null},"spec":{"resourceAttributes":{"namespace":"default","verb":"create","resource":"pods"}},"status":{"allowed":false}}
I0426 20:27:33.008875    4149 round_trippers.go:419] curl -k -v -XPOST  -H "Impersonate-User: system:serviceaccount:default:jenkins" -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.14.0 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/641856d" 'https://172.22.1.3/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectaccessreviews'
I0426 20:27:34.935506    4149 round_trippers.go:438] POST https://172.22.1.3/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectaccessreviews 201 Created in 1926 milliseconds
I0426 20:27:34.935550    4149 round_trippers.go:444] Response Headers:
I0426 20:27:34.935564    4149 round_trippers.go:447]     Audit-Id: 631abed7-b27b-4eca-b267-4d7db0f1aa21
I0426 20:27:34.935576    4149 round_trippers.go:447]     Content-Type: application/json
I0426 20:27:34.935588    4149 round_trippers.go:447]     Date: Fri, 26 Apr 2019 14:57:34 GMT
I0426 20:27:34.935599    4149 round_trippers.go:447]     Content-Length: 378
I0426 20:27:34.935724    4149 request.go:942] Response Body: {"kind":"SelfSubjectAccessReview","apiVersion":"authorization.k8s.io/v1","metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null},"spec":{"resourceAttributes":{"namespace":"default","verb":"create","resource":"pods"}},"status":{"allowed":true,"reason":"RBAC: allowed by RoleBinding \"jenkins-ns-default/default\" of Role \"jenkins-ns-default\" to User \"system:serviceaccount:default:jenkins\""}}
yes
```

You can view detailed description of SubjectAccessReview API here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#subjectaccessreview-v1-authorization

Read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/

Comment: If you could extend this answer to include the ["Check API access" portion/summary of the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/), I can mark it as complete/accepted. Thank you.